# yesod cast "responseBody" to a haskell type

Tags: haskell, yesod

the following code makes an api call in yesod. the question is how do i "cast" the resulting object to a predefined haskell type?

```
Network.HTTP.Conduit.withManager $ \manager -> do
    response <- http req manager
    resBody <- responseBody response C.$$+- sinkParser json
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ T.pack (show resBody)
```

example output log

```
Object (fromList [("val1",Number 1.0),("val2",String "text")])
```

all the attempts i have made to decode with Aeson or fromJSON are failing.

much appreciated

yunis

Answer (score 2):

Where the value came from doesn't seem to matter. You've got a hold of a piece of data with type `Aeson.Value`, so you just have to figure out how to succeed in your attempts with fromJSON.

Here's a bit of code adapted from the docs for [the FromJSON class](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.11/aeson-1.2.4.0/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HashMap

import Data.Aeson ((.:))
import Data.Text (Text)

-- this is the data you already have, which you named resBody
resBody :: Aeson.Value
resBody = Aeson.Object $
  HashMap.fromList
    [ ("val1", Aeson.Number 1.0)
    , ("val2", Aeson.String "text")]

-- Step 1: create a custom Haskell data type to house the data.
-- I named it Coord to match the example code from the link above,
-- but you should probably give it a more meaningful name.
data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Text }
  deriving (Show)

-- Step 2: write a FromJSON instance for your custom data type.
-- In this case, it is almost identical to the example code in the docs.
instance Aeson.FromJSON Coord where
  parseJSON = Aeson.withObject "Coord" $ \v -> Coord
    <$> v .: "val1"
    <*> v .: "val2"
```

Giving it a spin in the repl

```
ghci> -- Here's our data
ghci> resBody
Object (fromList [("val1",Number 1.0),("val2",String "text")])
ghci> -- Next, we decode using fromJSON, annotating the result as our desired type
ghci> Aeson.fromJSON resBody :: Aeson.Result Coord
Success (Coord {x = 1.0, y = "text"})
```

Comment: Ok so i have it working now... firstly, your answer was extremely close to what i am working on with very subtle differences... nevertheless, i got the following error when testing your code snippet: `Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Aeson.FromJSON’`. instead i used the following: `let result = Data.Aeson.Types.fromJSON resBody :: Data.Aeson.Types.Result Coord`.

Comment: apparently, i dont have a good enough rep to give your answer an UP vote haha ;-p

Comment: ... just realised you had `import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson` in your code snippet, i didnt have that while testing, i presume with that your code snippet would have worked for me too :) @DanBurton